Yearly comparison of the moderations
The below table is made for comparison of the yearly moderation of 2019, 2020, and 2021.




Action
Mod.    '21
Mod¹ '20
Mod '19

Com. '21
Com¹ '20
Com¹    19




Users suspended²
1
5
4

15
8
14


Users destroyed³
12
19
9

0
0
0


Users deleted
4
7
5

0
0
0


Users contacted
4
13
14

0
0
0


User suspensions lifted early

1



0



Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue
78
109
199

958
1,033
1,563


Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue
5
18
52

86
106
192


Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue
1
6
16

155
196
182


Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue
0
0
14

164
196
197


Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue
6



519




Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue
2
22
62

1,227
2,193
2,353


Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue
0



123




Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue
84
192
490

1,000
1,145
1,866


Tags merged
2
12
6

0
0
0


Tag synonyms proposed
5
15
3

1
2
0


Tag synonyms created
4
17
3

0
0
0


Revisions redacted

1



0



Questions unprotected


1



0


Questions reopened
36
22
54

0
1
0


Questions protected
1
7
7

5
2
11


Questions migrated
85
132
190

1
0
0


Questions merged
12
4
7

0
0
0


Questions flagged⁵
3
3
13

311
660
587


Questions closed
605
763
1,181

112
100
201


Question flags handled⁵
172
309
331

136
351
267


Posts unlocked
1
3
0

20
27
34


Posts undeleted
20
23
7

57
86
99


Posts locked
10
10
5

105
152
233


Posts deleted⁶
209
215
266

1,250
1,502
2,132


Posts bumped
0
0
0

746
595
435


Escalations to the Community Manager team

2
3


0
0


Comments undeleted
38
28
18

0
0
0


Comments flagged
0
1
24

106
116
850


Comments deleted⁷
1,200
1,360
1,680

1,385
2,092
3,219


Comment flags handled
97
74
164

9
43
710


Answers flagged
0
5
33

269
379
444


Answer flags handled
236
356
425

33
28
52


All comments on a post moved to chat
11
31
38

0
0
0


Bounties canceled


1



0




The superscript definition can be found in 2021.

can you add the key for the subscripts?

Yeah, it was a relatively uneventful year. Note that I did sometimes have to reopen questions to perform some action or other that is not possible on closed questions, so that number may be somewhat skewed. Still, nice to see that some or the more positive actions have increased, even though the rest decreased.

@MaartenBodewes should I write this under the 2021 moderation question? I can add more years. Maybe this come into a tradition, too,

Uh, let's see how popular this Q becomes first.

@bdegnan the same footnote as in the Jnat's report. Do you still want me to copy those?

@kelalaka ah!  no need now that I know where to look for it.  Thanks.
